# Wheres exactly Asp .Net MVC access rule information is stored in a sql server DB?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, access-rules

Where does sql asp net mvc stores role access in a sql database if it actually does?

I found information regarding user membership and roles but not about access rules.

Comment: You have 11 questions asked without anything accepted.  You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some research on the SqlMembershipProvider. There's a good tutorial on the schema it creates on the [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs).

In short, if you use the [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) tool, the appropriate tables will be created in your database, prefixed with 'aspnet_'.

**Edit:**

As for access rules, those are not stored in the database. In MVC, authorization is generally accomplished in code using the [Authorize attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), either at the action level or sometimes for an entire controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
 {
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         return View();
     }

     public ActionResult About()
     {
         return View();
     }

     [Authorize]
     public ActionResult AuthenticatedUsers()
     {
         return View();
     }

     [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
     public ActionResult AdministratorsOnly()
     {
         return View();
     }

     [Authorize(Users = "Betty, Johnny")]
     public ActionResult SpecificUserOnly()
     {
         return View();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I know that... As I wrote earlier I found information regarding user membership and roles in that structure but not about access rules.

Comment: @user1827417 Ok, then I guess I don't understand what you mean by 'access rules'. Can you clarify?

Comment: @user1827417 Also see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983558/store-asp-net-access-rules-on-sql-server

Comment: I can select a folder and set users ou role to access this folder. The folder has a path and I presume the system need to store that information somewhere in the database to check if a user or a group has permission to access this folder. Where this information is kept? I don´t see any folder path in my database. This was my question.

Comment: Thanks. I found the attribute.